# Ruby on Rails - Store current Url to redirect after destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, destroy

Because of my logged-in check before action, when deleting an object I cannot use the `redirect_back`.

Which one is the best way to store the current `url` somewhere, problably in `session helper`, and then redirect to that value in any controller?

Please help, this issue is affecting all my associated controllers.

Redirect back sends me to edit/show, which is nil now.

Im currently deleting from the parent:

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

 # Forgets a persistent session.
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id, role_id: current_user.role_id, action:"Logoff")
    @current_user = nil
  end

# Redirects to stored Location (or to the default)
def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)
    session.delete(:forwarding_url)
end

def store_location
     session[:forwarding_url] = request.url if request.get?
end 

end





class AddressesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user

    def address_params
        params.require(:address).permit(:id, :no, :street, :suburb, :code, :details, :city_id, :addressable_type, :addressable_id)
    end


    def new
        if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canwrite?)
        @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"New")
            @addresses = Address.new(:addressable_type => params[:addressable_type],:addressable_id => params[:addressable_id])
        else
        @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"New !Access Denied! ")
        flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to create Addresses."
        redirect_to :back
        end
    end

    def create
        if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canwrite?)
        @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Create", details: address_params)
            @address = Address.new(address_params)
            if @address.save
            flash[:notice] = 'Address Saved'
            redirect_to @address.addressable
            else
            render "new"
            end
        else
        @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Create !Access Denied! ")
        flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to create Addresses."
        redirect_to :back
        end
    end


    def edit
        if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canupdate?)
        @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Edit", details: params[:id])
            @addresss = Address.find(params[:id])
        else
        @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Edit !Access Denied! ", details: params[:id])
        flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to edit Addresses."
        redirect_to :back
        end
    end

    def update
        if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canupdate?)
        @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Update", details: address_params)
            @addresss = Address.find(params[:id])
            if @addresss.update_attributes(address_params)
            redirect_to @address.addressable
                flash[:notice] = 'Account Updated'
            else 
            render "edit"
            flash[:error]
            end
        else
        flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to edit Addresss."
        redirect_to back
        end
    end

    def show
        if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canread?)
        @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"View", details: params[:id])
            @addresses = Address.find(params[:id])
        else
        @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"View !Access Denied! ", details: params[:id])
        flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to view Addresss."
        redirect_to back
        end
    end

    def destroy
        if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:candelete?)
            @address = Address.find(params[:id])
            @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Delete", details: params[:id])
            @address.destroy
            redirect_to :back
            flash[:notice] = 'Address Deleted'
        else
        flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to delete Addresss."
        redirect_to :back
        end
    end


    # Before Filters

    # Confirms if User is logged-in
    def logged_in_user
     unless logged_in?
     flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
     redirect_to root_path
     end
    end
end
```

Comment: I would think you can't do a `redirect_to :back` because the previous view was the `show` page for the deleted object?  I can't see why your `logged_in` check has anything to do with it.  Are you saying if you remove that check you CAN redirect?  Could you show some sample code?

Comment: The logged_in check stores the current url, same with the access rights, so the redirect back send me to the show/edit path, I need to redirect 2 steps back in this case. The redirect_back or redirect_to back both have same effect and they are working good whit authentication. So I really need a secondary path storage location or learn how to set up a redirect to 2 steps back

Answer (score 5):

You can store multiple redirect_to paths... best to use a separate before_action to do this, in your ApplicationController

```
before_action :store_back_paths

def store_back_paths

  # if session[:back_path] doesn't exist, create it as an empty array

  session[:back_path] ||= []

  # add the current path as a new entry in the array

  session[:back_path] << request.referer

  # while there are more than five entries, drop the oldest entries 
  # this is to ensure we're not storing too many entries

  session[:back_path].shift while session[:back_path].count > 5
end
```

When doing a normal redirect, use pop which removes the last element in the array and returns the removed value.

```
redirect_to session[:back_path].pop
```

When doing a redirect after a destroy drop the last entry (which points to the show page for the destroyed item) and then redirect to the path previous to that.

```
session[:back_path].pop # drops the last entry   
redirect_to session[:back_path].pop
```

Comment: Thats good, I was thinking in something like that, storing the last 3 sequentially, but my lack of knowledge limits me. I have added the code so if you have some time to explain better I would be eternally grateful

Comment: Ok, I've reworked it into more usable code and added more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I just store the location where I want to go, just before I commit the delete:

```
def destroy
  @child = Child.find_by params[:id]
  parent = @child.parent # or whatever
  @child.destroy
  flash[:notice] = 'Deleted'
  redirect_to parent
end
```

If you want to store in a session, which I don't use for destroying, but do for other things:

```
def destroy
  @child = Child.find_by params[:id]
  session[:return_link] = parent_path(@child.parent) # or whatever
  @child.destroy
  flash[:notice] = 'Deleted'
  redirect_to session[:return_link]
end
```

of course you can then set and return from any point, I use it to allow the user to navigate a subsection of the site, then exit out, by recording the activity referrer when the do a show action into the subsection, and display buttons to the session'd path do get out, at the exit point they joined at any point.

You have to add a few tests for it being set, in the case you don't set it of course, should you be using a link.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the second option. I`m using polymorphic tables, not sure if the first option can be used, can I change/use .parent by polymorphic?

Comment: sorry. .parent was an example class. please insert your own method - normally for polymorphic I put a belongs_to in the base class that you defined, and then all subclasses have the belongs to. Then use whatever that belongs_to is.. This assumes all of the polymorphic classes belongs_to a certain type of object, if not, the define a get_parent method for each type of class, that does return the path of the parent (or object you want to get..)